# how to join string values of list in columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have a dataframe:

```
  id                val
0  a  ['word1', 'word2']
1  b  ['word3','word4','word5']
2  c  ['word6', 'word6','word7']
```

How can I get such dataframe:

```
  id                val
0  a  word1 word2
1  b  word3 word4 word5
2  c  word6 word6 word7
```

I tried do this with many ways of `str.join()`, but it doesn't work,
and I'm out of ideas.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If your using pandas version 0.23.1 or higher, you can use:

```
df['val'] = df['val'].str.join(' ')
```

[out]

```
  id                val
0  a        word1 word2
1  b  word3 word4 word5
2  c  word6 word6 word7
```